# Using index of ObservableList in TableView column JavaFX

Tags: javafx, indexing, tableview

I am currently trying to show the index of my ObservableList to a TableView column. The only solutions I have found are for creating superficial indexes. But I need the actual index so that I may sort the TableView accordingly.

```
 cargoTable.setItems(um.getCargoList());
 cargoTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, CargoType>("cargoType"));
 ownerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, Customer>("owner"));
 ownerColumn.setComparator(new Comparator<Customer>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
         return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
     }
     });
 sizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, Integer>("size"));
 propertiesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, String>("properties"));
 hazardsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, Hazard>("hazards"));
 depositDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Cargo, Date>("date"));
```

My TableView Observes a List with Cargoes and every column in the TableView represents a property of the Cargo inside the List. Everything works perfectly but I just cant seem to be able to figure a way to use a column showing the index of this list.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why is the index of the cargo of any importance to the user?

Comment: I am simulating a Cargo Storage. The index represents in this case the position of the corresponding cargo inside the Storage

Comment: I would not use the index as an identifier of this, because the index can change, even if you didn't mean for it to. I would instead add another field to the cargo class and use that as its "location" in the storage unit. This will make it easier to track and manage.

Comment: You are probably right. But I am still wondering if there is a way to do it, with index as position!

Comment: Well, as long as you know. I will need to think on it. Someone else may have an answer for you though.

Comment: I appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

This is untested.

You can use a custom `cellValueFactory` for your column and have some different logic in it. Something similar to:

```
indexCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
    Cargo item = data.getValue();
    int index = table.getItems().indexOf(item);
    return new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(index));
});
```

This basically says for this column, give me the item this cell needs to look at, and look up its index based on the list set to the table, then return it.

This should work, and of course you will need to edit for class and list correctness, etc. but the idea still stands.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding how to tailor your example to my case. I am specifically having trouble implementing data.getValue(). How is my code suppose to know that the data.getValue() is always the latest Cargo added?

Comment: I tried                                                                 indexColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
            Cargo item = um.getCargoList().get(um.getCargoList().size()-1);
            int index = cargoTable.getItems().indexOf(item);
            return new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(index));
        });        but now the whole Column shows the same index for all cargoes

Comment: @loaIoakim Ioakim you're using the last cargo for all rows so of course they all show the same number. The code Hypnic Jerk provided should do what you want, I'm not sure why you're not using it as is.

Comment: data.getValue() returns me The CargoHolder which is the class which contains the ObservableList with the cargoes. I need to somehow access that List and get the Cargo which was just added

Comment: Okay I am dumb. The code shown was totally right. Now it works ! thank you so much :)